# Does this function have to be constant?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Suppose that a continuous function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}_+$ satisfies the following property for all $x \in [0,1]$:
$$
  f(x) 
  = \frac{3}{2} f\left(\frac{3}{4} x\right) 
  - \frac{1}{2} f\left(\frac{1}{2} x\right).
$$
For example: this is clearly satisfied when $f(x) =c = \frac{3}{2}c-\frac{1}{2}c$. Are there other functions that satisfy this property?

Comment: If we had not required continuity, we could easily find many non-constant such functions. Since we require continuity I'm less certain.

Comment: One such non-continuous example is $f(x)=a/x$ for $x>0$, $f(0)=b$ for any constants $a,b \geq 0$.